# Autofac with Lazy Metadata

Tags: c#, metadata, lazy-loading, autofac

I am trying to understand the use of strongly typed Metadata consumption with autofac.

In the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Metadata#Consuming_Metadata) it says:

> In .NET 4.0, Autofac supports the Meta and System.Lazy types for consuming values from the strongly-typed interface:

But there is no type Lazy in System that expects two type parameters, there is only Lazy.

Am I missing something?

I try to accomplish the following:

```
IEnumerable<Meta<Lazy<IService>, IServiceTypMeta>> services
```

This works fine. Metainformation can be consumed before Services are instanciated. But if I understand the docs correctly on should be able to write:

```
IEnumerable<Lazy<IService, IServiceTypMeta>> services
```

to accomplish the same with out the autofac related Meta class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll.
See: [Lazy< T, TMetadata > Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd986615%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)